# Как найти объект в массиве?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function User(props) {
  const { gistName } = useParams()
  const gists = useSelector(state => state.gists.data)

  const item = gists.find(item => item.files.`${gistName}`.filename === gistName);
  console.log(item)

  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Нужно найти объект в массиве зная имя файла

```js
data: [
      {
        url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/55f8d84eaecb5e50eae9acd6120f2298',
        forks_url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/55f8d84eaecb5e50eae9acd6120f2298/forks',
        commits_url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/55f8d84eaecb5e50eae9acd6120f2298/commits',
        id: '55f8d84eaecb5e50eae9acd6120f2298', // этот id
        node_id: 'MDQ6R2lzdDU1ZjhkODRlYWVjYjVlNTBlYWU5YWNkNjEyMGYyMjk4',
        git_pull_url: 'https://gist.github.com/55f8d84eaecb5e50eae9acd6120f2298.git',
        git_push_url: 'https://gist.github.com/55f8d84eaecb5e50eae9acd6120f2298.git',
        html_url: 'https://gist.github.com/55f8d84eaecb5e50eae9acd6120f2298',
        files: {
          'LinkToken_Matic.v6.sol': {
            filename: 'LinkToken_Matic.v6.sol', //зная filename нужно найти id,
            type: 'text/plain',
            language: 'Solidity',
            raw_url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/krebernisak/55f8d84eaecb5e50eae9acd6120f2298/raw/587e88112d280ca3dcc6e0b834cbc24ebbe5389d/LinkToken_Matic.v6.sol',
            size: 30783
          }
        },
        'public': true,
        created_at: '2020-10-21T14:48:04Z',
        updated_at: '2020-10-21T14:48:05Z',
        description: 'LinkToken on Matic Network v6',
        comments: 0,
        user: null,
        comments_url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/55f8d84eaecb5e50eae9acd6120f2298/comments',
        owner: {
          login: 'krebernisak',
          id: 615877,
          node_id: 'MDQ6VXNlcjYxNTg3Nw==',
          avatar_url: 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/615877?v=4',
          gravatar_id: '',
          url: 'https://api.github.com/users/krebernisak',
          html_url: 'https://github.com/krebernisak',
          followers_url: 'https://api.github.com/users/krebernisak/followers',
          following_url: 'https://api.github.com/users/krebernisak/following{/other_user}',
          gists_url: 'https://api.github.com/users/krebernisak/gists{/gist_id}',
          starred_url: 'https://api.github.com/users/krebernisak/starred{/owner}{/repo}',
          subscriptions_url: 'https://api.github.com/users/krebernisak/subscriptions',
          organizations_url: 'https://api.github.com/users/krebernisak/orgs',
          repos_url: 'https://api.github.com/users/krebernisak/repos',
          events_url: 'https://api.github.com/users/krebernisak/events{/privacy}',
          received_events_url: 'https://api.github.com/users/krebernisak/received_events',
          type: 'User',
          site_admin: false
        },
        truncated: false
      },
```

Comment: а url как выглядит?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/:gistName ,подставляется автоматически имя файла

Comment: const item = gists.find(item => item.files[gistName] && item.files[gistName].filename ===gistName );     так м.б.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов спасибо,все получилось